# Is it possible to search for words/content in an answer given to a favorite question?

Tags: feature-request, support, bookmarks, search

Sometimes I'm searching for some specific answer that was given to a question that I favorited. However, using the `infavorites:mine` functionality, I can only search through the favorited questions, not the text of an answer. This is easily proved by the fact that `infavorites:mine is:answer` returns nothing.

Is there a way to do this kind of search?

If it is possible with the data explorer, is there already some query to do that?

If not, wouldn't this be a useful feature given that the intended use (for what I was able to understand) for the "favorites" feature is to have a kind of bookmark, which would consequently probably concern the whole discussion, or maybe even just some answers to the question?

Comment: FYI: If it was older, you can always do it in Data Exchange queries.

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure I understand you. If it was older what?

Comment: Older than 1 week/month, or whatever data exchange site's lag time is

Comment: @DVK 1 week.. updates are on sunday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind if [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is only updated once a week (on Sunday, 03:00 UTC) you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/521942?search=wiggle&UserId=58382)

```sql
select a.id as [Post Link]
     , a.creationdate
     , a.score
     , a.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , q.creationdate as [Q Created]
     , q.score as [Q Score]
from  posts q
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
inner join votes v on v.postid = q.id 
where v.votetypeid = 5 -- favorite
and v.userid = ##userid:int?58382##
and a.body like '%' + ##search:string## + '%'
```

This query joins the posts table for questions and answers based on your favorite vote. As that resultset will be rather small it is not much of a problem to do a wildcard like text search on the body content of posts.

When run today the result resembles this:

[image: search result for word wiggle]